# Animate circle along sine curve

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-animate

I am trying to replicate the visuals of f.lux using jQuery which looks like [this](https://giphy.com/gifs/26hitMngplybFIKXK) (sorry for the poor quality). Basically, it is a circle following a sine wave path. I have looked at the [jQuery.path](https://github.com/weepy/jquery.path) animations and I tried replicating the animation, but my sine wave is choppy since it is drawn using CSS. Is there a way to draw the sine wave so it is smooth and then animate the circle following the sine wave path? I couldn't get a fiddle working but this is what my animation currently looks like [now](http://giphy.com/gifs/3o7TKJMpaONYNqQtWw). My animation also does not loop back to where it starts unlike the f.lux animation.

I am not sure what the limits are for this either, will I need to make f.lux's background (the blue and pink halves of the sine wave) and then lay the animation on top of it or can I make the whole visual using Javascript, CSS, and jQuery?

Does anybody have any ideas or can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

To make your line smoother, you can use a svg element, like so :

```
<svg width="190" height="160" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path d="M10 80 C 40 10, 65 20, 95 80" stroke="black" fill="#E0E0E0"/>
  <path d="M95 80 C 105 100, 150 150, 180 80" stroke="black" fill="#EEEEEE"/>
</svg>
```

This uses two different bézier curves so you can use different colors for your background. You will have to change the values a bit to match you desired width/height and curvature. There is an explanation on svg paths here : https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths.

You can create an insert a svg element with javascript or jQuery SVG if you don't have access to the HTML source file.